# How can I make an existing numpy array a structured array?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to give an existing numpy array named columns.  I've tried to name the columns in the following way:

```
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(3,3))
names = ['a','b','c']
types = ['f4']*len(names)
t = list(zip(names,types))

Y= np.array(X, dtype=t)
```

However, when I call `Y['a']`, I am given a 3x3 array rather than the first column of X, which is 3x1.

How can I give an existing array named columns?  What is my error in my example?

Comment: Watch out, `np.random.normal` probably returns `f8`

Comment: Sometimes the `X.tolist()` is needed as an intermediate form.  But it might also need to be converted to a list of tuples

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `.view`, which reinterprets existing memory in a new way.

```
names = ['a','b','c']
types = [X.dtype]*len(names)
t = list(zip(names,types))
Y = X.view(t)
```

For this to work, you need to match the dtype of `X` - `f4` is probably not correct.

Your code is equivalent to `X.astype(t)`. When converting to a struct array, that tries to set every field to the same value.

Comment: Great, it looks like `veiw` is what I need.  i'll read the docs to ensure I use it correctly.